SELECT and WHERE are returning different outputs
I'm trying to figure out why SELECT Holiday_Flag = 1 and WHERE Holiday_Flag = 1 return different outputs. The reason why I want to use WHERE is so that the Holiday_Flag column isn't displayed during output. However, they are both using data from the same table and the column Holiday_Flags is INT.
The code is below:
SELECT Date, SUM(CAST(Weekly_Sales AS FLOAT)) AS Weekly_Sales
FROM WalmartSalesClean 
WHERE Holiday_Flag = 1
GROUP BY Date
ORDER BY Weekly_Sales DESC;

OUTPUT:

It only contains 10 rows.
But this code contains 143 rows:
SELECT Holiday_Flag = 1, Date, SUM(CAST(Weekly_Sales AS FLOAT)) AS Weekly_Sales
FROM WalmartSalesClean
GROUP BY Date
ORDER BY Weekly_Sales DESC;

OUTPUT:

I've tried WHERE='1' or SELECT = '1', but it doesn't seem to change anything. Why do SELECT and WHERE return different outputs, even though they're both filtering for Holiday_Flags = 1?

Your two queries don't do the same thing. SELECT Holiday_Flag = 1 does not do what you think it does. The WHERE is the proper solution, and the SELECT Holiday_Flag = 1 is just wrong. You're asking why apples aren't the same as oranges - why does a properly written query return different results than one that is improperly written. You can prove it yourself - just execute SELECT Holiday_Flag = 1 FROM WalmartSalesClean by itself.

What kind of database are you using? Also: we don't post images of sample data or results here. There is a table formatting option. Use it.


even though they're both filtering for Holiday_Flags = 1?

Where did you get the idea the SELECT clause will ever filter rows? That. Does. Not. Happen. You can only filter rows through WHERE, ON, and HAVING clauses (and maybe now QUALIFY in some databases).
Instead, SELECT Holiday_Flag = 1 defines a new column in the results named Holiday_Flag with a value that is always a constant 1, regardless of whatever value any Holiday_Flag column in any source table(s) might have been. It does NOT compare the Holiday_Flag column from any source table(s) with the value 1. It does not and cannot filter any rows.


The reason why I want to use WHERE is so that the Holiday_Flag column isn't displayed during output.

Great. So do that. What's the problem again?

Forgive me in raising this but OP may be a newcomer in SQL as well as SO. Your correct answer reads a bit rough. Let's be more welcoming, so we can be an SQL guru like you one day! :)
